# Google Coral Dev board vs Asus Tinker Edge T

Tags: tpu, google-coral, asus

Does this:
https://www.asus.com/gr/AIoT-Industrial-Solutions/Tinker-Edge-T/
have any difference with this:
https://coral.ai/products/dev-board/
?? For example can I train a custom CNN? Has anyone experience to give an advice? I want to buy a SBC with TPU in order to train a CNN faster but the information I found on google do not help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asus Tinker Edge T actually have the same edgetpu that is on the dev board. I believe the SOM is exactly the same and only the base board are different. 
The edgetpu are targeted for inferencing only, not training, so you probably won't profit from it. However, you can take advantage of fast inference time to do things like backprop which allows you to do some transfer learning:
https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/retrain-classification-ondevice-backprop/

Comment: Can I run on Coral Dev the CIFAR-10 training from here? https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-a-cnn-from-scratch-for-cifar-10-photo-classification/